# How can I find the value n satisfying the equation?

Tags: equation-solving

I would like to find the value *n* satisfying following equation . How can I do it in Mathematica?

15411 == 123*Fibonacci[n] + 31*Fibonacci[n + 1]

Comment: `FindInstance[ 15411 == (123*Fibonacci[n] + 31*Fibonacci[n + 1]), n, Reals]`

Comment: ah, v10.1 yields 11..  (oddly it does not find the result if you make domain `Integers` )

Comment: Try FindInstance[
 15411 == (123*Fibonacci[n] + 31*Fibonacci[n + 1]) && n > 0, n, Reals], which yields the result $n=11$ (MMA v. 11.2.0 otherwise yields a negative root near $-12.7544$).

Comment: Using a finite interval makes it return `11`: `FindInstance[{15411 == (123*Fibonacci[n] + 31*Fibonacci[n + 1]), 0 < n < 200000, n ∈ Integers}, n]`

Comment: `Fibonacci` is defined on reals other than integers, so could just use `FindRoot`. `In[6]:= FindRoot[15411 == 123*Fibonacci[n] + 31*Fibonacci[n + 1],{n,9}]         

Out[6]= {n -> 11.}
`

Answer (score 1):

You can use either [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) or [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) if you specify an range for `n` which contains the solution. The range does not have to be tight.

```
eqn = 15411 == 123*Fibonacci[n] + 31*Fibonacci[n + 1];

sol1 = Solve[{eqn, -50 < n < 50}, n, Integers]

(* {{n -> 11}} *)
```

Verifying,

```
eqn /. sol1[[1]]

(* True *)
```

Or

```
sol2 = Reduce[{eqn, -50 < n < 50}, n, Integers] // ToRules

(* {n -> 11} *)
```

Comment: or even .. `(Pick[#, (eqn  /. n -> # ) & /@ #] &@Range[-50, 50] )`